# Question on integral evaluation in Gauss-Bonnet Theorem

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry

In University I have to visit a Topology/Geometry course for my bachelor degree. This course is based on Analysis I/II, so multivariable calculus, Riemann Integrals in multiple dimension and the very basic definitions of metric spaces and convergence. Since I like the subject a lot, I wanted to learn more and currently I am studying the brilliant books by John M. Lee (Topological and smooth manifolds, Riemannian manifolds) since it covers the topics in a more formal way then the course does. On p. 167 in Riemannian manifolds one finds the well-known Gauss-Bonnet Theorem:

> If $M$ is a triangulated, compact, oriented, Riemannian $2$-manifold,
>   then $$\int_M K dA = 2\pi \chi(M).$$

So my questions are:

- How should I interpret the integral? Lebesgue or Riemann integral? Since nothing is mentioned in the book, I think it should be a Riemann integral since I do not know how to evaluate an integral over a surface, which brings me to my next question.
- How do I evaluate the lefthandside? I mean, $M$ could be any abstract manifold with no embedding. I mean, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we work with the formula using the parametrization and so on (which gets also messy if $M$ is complex).

Comment: Do you mean "How do I evaluate the left hand side" (which is where the integral is)?

Comment: @tracing Of course, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integration on manifolds, you should refer to [Integration of differential forms (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Integration_2).

The type of integral itself (Riemann or Lebesgue) is not so important as at the end the functions being integrated are continuous.